# How to get string value from Select tag in ASP.NET Core using C#?

Tags: list, asp.net-core, select

I want to get the string value from my HTML `<Select>` tag in ASP.NET Core using C#, but I don't know how to do it...

```
<select asp-for="selectcity" asp-items="Model.Options"  
        name="SelectCityTag" style="width:-moz-available">
</select>
```

Comment: Unsure what is the aim/result that you try to achieve. Are you trying to pass the selected option label to the controller? Further elaborate what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("Selection");
        $("#Selection").val(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    });
    function changefunc(val) {
        $("#Selection").val($("#selectcity").val());
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectionProcessing", "Home"))
{
    <input id="Selection" name="Selection" type="hidden" />
    <select asp-for="selectcity" asp-items="Model.Options"  name="SelectCityTag" 
        onchange="changefunc(this.value)"
        style="width:-moz-available">
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Process Selected value</button>
}
```

And in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectionProcessing(string selection)
{
    // your code...    
}
```

Comment: your answer is too long. i dont want to use javascript.